# How to use CSS to control the style of an HTML unordered list?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Basically I want to control the margin on the left of the list. Here's how I have it structured:

```
<li> 
<a href="http://link.com">Main</a> 
<ul> 
    <li> 
        <a href="http://link.com"  title="">Sub1</a>
    </li> 
    <li> 
        <a href="http://link.com"  title="">Sub2</a> 
    </li> 
</ul>
</li>
```

The sub-sections are too far to the right with the current style I'm using. How do I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My ul "reset" looks something like this:

```
ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove or at least lessen the margin/padding.

```
li ul { padding: 0; margin: 0 }
li ul li { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

This should make it flush with the main section list items, adjust to taste.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add class attribute to the sublist:

```
<li> 
<a href="http://link.com">Main</a> 
<ul class="sublist"> 
    <li> 
        <a href="http://link.com"  title="">Sub1</a>
    </li> 
    <li> 
        <a href="http://link.com"  title="">Sub2</a> 
    </li> 
</ul>
</li>
```

And put this css for it:

```
ul.sublist{
   margin-left:20px;
}
```